# Failed to rename S3AFileStatus

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am getting following error when running on local EC2 with 'hadoop-3.1.1' and 'spark-2.4.0-bin-without-hadoop'.

```
[Stage 6:>                                                       (0 + 32) / 200]
2019-10-03 15:40:34 ERROR SparkHadoopMapRedUtil:91 - Error committing the output of task: attempt_20191003154033_0006_m_000000_0
java.io.IOException: 
Failed to rename S3AFileStatus{path=s3a://mck-547-data/data_dev/z_ref/ref_proc/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20191003154033_0006_m_000000_0/part-00000-f3c3b55e-97e9-47d1-a7e2-1b35177e6206-c000.snappy.parquet; 
isDirectory=false; length=7945; replication=1; blocksize=33554432; modification_time=1570117234000; access_time=0; owner=kk_shinde; group=kk_shinde; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false} isEmptyDirectory=FALSE 
to s3a://mck-547-data/data_dev/z_ref/ref_proc/part-00000-f3c3b55e-97e9-47d1-a7e2-1b35177e6206-c000.snappy.parquet
```

I googled and all the links re committer as below.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14161

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.md

Tried the option of adding the below properties to spark-conf:

```
#spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.buffer.dir /tmp/spark_tmp/
#spark.hadoop.s.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode replace
```

But still getting this error. Just wondering what would be the easy solution. We are trying for an option of writing to local and doing S3 sync in the code. But that is very crude way of doing it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also added the property: `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name directory`

Comment: for the s3a committers to kick in you need to be running hadoop-3.1+ binaries and a build of Spark with the extra binding classes in it. What versions do you have?

Comment: thanks Steve! The version of hadoop and spark I am using are -  'hadoop-3.1.1' and 'spark-2.4.0-bin-without-hadoop'. Are they with extra binding classes or am I missing something?

Comment: There are some extra binding classes which are you not in the shipping spark release; the patch has only gone in to a more recent version. They are in the HDP 3 spark binaries, if you can grab them.

It's only a couple of classes, but it is needed to fix up parquet and other committers to be pluggable,

Comment: Can you advise which binaries and how to bind them. Or any document explaining this?

Comment: @Kirti Did you resolve the issue.could you please provide the solution

Comment: I could not resolve this issue, so we wrote a class to first write a local temp space and then syn to S3.

Comment: @SteveLoughran - The version of hadoop and spark I am using are - 'hadoop-3.1.1' and 'spark-2.4.0-bin-without-hadoop'.

Comment: @Steve Loughran- I was trying to make directory committer work on spark 2.4.4 with hadoop 3.1.3 - all looks good except it writes no data :). SUCCESS file is is non 0, but it is the only file in the dir :). Can I download and add those missing classes to spark? We are in real need of normal committer that can work right with S3. Thanks a lot!